# 2003 Ford Taurus SE, Vulcan engine - Chirping sound from intake manifold, car stalling out?

Tags: engine, ford, fuel-system, stall, taurus

Over the past 2 weeks or so my car has been making a chirping sound near the intake manifold and the accelerator. The chirping sound comes and go, and about a week ago I had an issue where my car stalled out when driving at a low speed out of a parking lot. I put in some dry gas seeing how the weather was extremely cold, and the stumbling and stalling out seemed to go away. However, today as I was leaving a Walmart parking lot my car stalled out several times and it definitely was directly related to the chirping sound. When the chirping sound would start up it would almost make like a "dying chirp" sound and the car would die. However, I could easily start the car back up each time but then I could only go a little bit forward and the car would die again. However, after about 4 or 5 stall outs I was able to drive the car to a more remote part of the parking lot where I opened up the hood and looked around. I was able to drive the car home, although it seemed like it was going to stall out again (the car wasn't chirping the whole ride home until near the end where the car started to stumble a bit). I am very confused by this because I can't really pinpoint it at all. Any ideas?

Comment: What model of car is this? Which engine?

Comment: 2003 Ford Taurus SE, Vulcan engine

Comment: One of my cars did this (the chirping) and it turned out to be a crack in the exhaust manifold. When it heated up, the crack would temporarily seal, which made the chirp go away. It didn't make the car stall though, I just had minor problems with the air/fuel mix because the oxygen sensor was giving erratic readings. It's probably a good idea to have someone stick a diagnostic machine on the car to see what's up.